# When i select an item in the dropdown the response won't come with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me.
I'm trying to make a dropdown menu, when you select something you will get an answer that is generated with javascript. When i run it local there is no problem at all. But when i put it online you don't get an answer anymore.
Can someone look at the code and tell me what i am doing wrong?

in debugger i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
  display

on this line:
 var txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;

PS: tried with a loop but wasn't working at all

```js
addEventListener('load',display,true);

function display(obj,gin01,gin02,gin03,gin04,gin05,gin06,gin07,gin08,gin09,gin10,
                 gin11,gin12,gin13,gin14,gin15,gin16,gin17,gin18,gin19,gin20,
                 gin21,gin22,gin23,gin24,gin25,gin26,gin27,gin28,gin29,gin30,
                 gin31,gin32,gin33,gin34,gin35,gin36,gin37,gin38,gin39,gin40,
                 gin41,gin42,gin43,gin44,gin45,gin46,gin47,gin48,gin49,gin50,
                 gin51,gin52,gin53,gin54,gin55,gin56,gin57,gin58,gin59,gin60,
                 gin61,gin62,gin63,gin64,gin65,gin66,gin67,gin68,gin69,gin70,
                 gin71,gin72,gin73,gin74,gin75,gin76,gin77,gin78,gin79,gin80) {

    var txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;


    document.getElementById(gin01).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin02).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin03).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin04).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin05).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin06).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin07).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin08).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin09).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin10).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin11).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin12).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin13).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin14).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin15).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin16).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin17).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin18).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin19).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin20).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin21).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin22).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin23).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin24).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin25).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin26).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin27).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin28).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin29).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin30).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin31).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin32).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin33).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin34).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin35).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin36).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin37).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin38).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin39).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin40).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin41).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin42).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin43).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin44).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin45).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin46).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin47).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin48).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin49).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin50).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin51).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin52).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin53).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin54).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin55).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin56).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin57).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin58).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin59).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin60).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin61).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin62).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin63).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin64).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin65).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin66).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin67).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin68).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin69).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin70).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin71).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin72).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin73).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin74).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin75).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin76).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin77).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin78).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin79).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(gin80).style.display = 'none';




    if ( txt.match(gin01) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin01).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin02) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin02).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin03) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin03).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin04) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin04).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin05) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin05).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin06) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin06).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin07) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin07).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin08) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin08).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin09) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin09).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin10) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin10).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin11) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin11).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin12) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin12).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin13) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin13).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin14) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin14).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin15) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin15).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin16) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin16).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin17) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin17).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin18) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin18).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin19) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin19).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin20) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin20).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin21) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin21).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin22) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin22).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin23) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin23).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin24) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin24).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin25) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin25).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin26) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin26).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin27) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin27).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin28) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin28).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin29) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin29).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin30) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin30).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin31) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin31).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin32) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin32).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin33) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin33).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin34) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin34).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin35) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin35).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin36) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin36).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin37) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin37).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin38) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin38).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin39) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin39).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin40) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin40).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin41) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin41).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin42) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin42).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin43) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin43).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin44) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin44).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin45) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin45).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin46) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin46).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin47) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin47).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin48) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin48).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin49) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin49).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin50) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin50).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin51) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin51).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin52) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin52).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin53) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin53).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin54) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin54).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin55) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin55).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin56) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin56).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin57) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin57).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin58) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin58).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin59) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin59).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin60) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin60).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin61) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin61).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin62) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin62).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin63) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin63).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin64) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin64).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin65) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin65).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin66) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin66).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin67) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin67).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin68) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin68).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin69) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin69).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin70) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin70).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin71) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin71).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin72) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin72).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin73) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin73).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin74) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin74).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin75) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin75).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin76) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin76).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin77) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin77).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin78) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin78).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin79) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin79).style.display = 'block';
    }
    if ( txt.match(gin80) ) {
        document.getElementById(gin80).style.display = 'block';
    }


}
```

Comment: I suggest you start by dumping  (`console.log(.....)`) what arguments your display function receives.

Comment: BTW: using loops you can greatly simplify your code, since you won't have to repeat all commands 80 times...

Comment: yes i know i have two versions one with a loop en the one i uploaded but both of them are the same i get the same error

Comment: Buddy pl. provide your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help you for recreating your code

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b5ses8kz/)

**JS**

```
$("p").css("display","none");

function disp(x) {
    var curVal = x; /* Stores Selected options Value*/
    var dis = curVal - 1; /*This is for eq() prop of JQuery*/
    $("p").hide(); /* To hide if previous one still visible */
    $("p:eq(" + dis + ")").fadeIn(); /* To make visible the selected respective div(in my case paragraph) */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="disp(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<p>I am display for Option 1</p>
<p>I am display for Option 2</p>
<p>I am display for Option 3</p>
<p>I am display for Option 4</p>
```

Comment: hmm when i try to run your code i only get the html dropdown and under it the four displayed options

Comment: could you give me a full html file were it is working because when i see your code in jsfiddle then it's exactly what i need but when i try to implement it and copy it to a html file then it's not working

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> Add this line inside your head tags in HTML file

Comment: This file is JQuery file, needed to run jquery, so either add this file online(just as i mention in above comment) or download it, save with a name along extension .js and add to your html file's head tags with your own path(path where you placed this file just like CSS external file). <script type="text/javascript" src="foldername/myjqueryfile.js"></script>

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you can upvote/accept the answer. Thanks!